# via is not working in geb

Tags: groovy, geb

I am trying to test login function using geb+spock+groovy.

I want the browser to go to login page, if user already logged in then the browser will redirect user to homepage, if the user hasn't logged in then execute login function.

Here is my code:

```
def setupSpec() {
    via loginPage
    if (page instanceof loginPage) {
        login()
    }
}
```

But `via` isn't working as expected, and I got this error:

> invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
>     (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-92-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

If I use `to loginPage`, then geb will check `at` for loginPage, which is not what I want because if user already logged in then `at` checking will fail.

Can someone please help? Thanks!!!

Comment: `to loginPage` works fine when user hasn't log in, so it should not be an issue in the loginPage and login() function.

Comment: `via` and `to` do the same. You can move the `if` statement one line above. Check for an element that is on the login page, or better yet, `catch` an exception then `login`.

Comment: Thanks! Removing `if` and using `try catch` fixes the issue :)